# No row with the given identifier exists: Strange behavior when changing a ManyToMany relationship from lazy to eager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

I am facing a strange behavior when I try to load an entity and I get the following exception

```
  org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: 
    No row with the given identifier exists: [com.xxx.entity.Role#4545]
```

My hibernate entities look so complex I hope I can make it simple as possible:

```
@Entity
class Employee {   
   @ManyToMany
   private List<BB> bbList = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
class BB extends CC{

}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
abstract class CC {
   @ManyToOne(optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ID_XXX_DIM", nullable = false)
   private Dimension dimension;
}

@Entity
class Dimension {
  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
}
```

What I am trying to do is to list `Employee` objects using hibernate criteria.
But it works only if I change

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

to

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

can you tell me why I get an exception when I use eager property

```
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: 
No row with the given identifier exists: [com.xxx.entity.Role#4545]
```

Comment: The error says that there's an ID on the foreign key column, that doesn't have a matching PK on the foreign table. Do you have FK constraints on the DB? And in particular in the many-to-many join table? if yes, check they are correct. If they are correct, you most probably have something wrong in your mapping, so please add the DDL of the tables.

Comment: @Augusto It's a bug in hibernate criteria which cause the generation of the same aliases for different primary key columns and like that we have an access to an entity with the wrong key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rootcause of this exception is a bug in Hibernate Criteria that generate a wrong SQL query with the same alias for different primary key.
This is a snapshot of the query generated and you can see the alias **ID2_8_** is duplicated for different tables columns.

```
select composite1_.ID_RSK_IND as ID2_8_, dimension8_.MNE_DIM as MNE3_90_4_, 
roles9_.ID_GRP_DIM as ID1_90_8_, role10_.ID_ROL as ID2_8_
```

Oracle can handle this situation but hibernate will try to load the entity with a key of the other entity.

As workaround i found that adding `@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)` will solve this bug I don't know why but it works.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```